# use of lockfile in script and it significance

Tags: linux, shell-script, lock

I have a code in which below line is used due to which i got stuck.I have hunted the web but did not understand well.just got to know the basic set of info as
below

*lockfile can be used to create one or more semaphore files. If lockfile can’t create all the specified files (in the specified order), it waits sleeptime (defaults to 8) seconds and retries the last file that didn’t succeed.*

Can any one please let me know the understanding.
Thanks
in advance
NOTE: LockFile is a path variable

```
if lockfile -1 -r0 ${LockFile}
then
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The point of `lockfile` is to protect the execution of some commands with a [lock (also called mutex)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science)). That is, consider the following program:

```
if lockfile "$LockFile"; then
  stuff
  more stuff
  rm -f "$LockFile"
else
  echo 1>&2 "Fatal error: another process has been keeping the lock for too long or the lock file is inaccessible"
  exit 3
fi
```

Only a single instance of the script at a time can be executing the `stuff; more stuff` part. If you start a second instance, then the second will wait until the first has finished (more precisely, until it's deleted the lock file), up to a certain maximum time given by the `-TIME` option.

With the parameter `-r0`, the second instance doesn't wait at all: it immediately goes to the `else` branch. So you can't run concurrent instance of this script (or this part of the script, if this is just one part of a bigger script).

Comment: What about -1 option!!

Comment: @api1411 1 is a number. It's the time to wait, except that it isn't used because `-r0` says not to wait.